# Tab completion - set of the folders name

Tags: powershell

I want to add tab completion for my param ($filter). I want to add all folders (contained in same directory as script) to Validate Set.

Below is my folder structure:

```
───test
   │   script.ps1
   │
   ├───Folder1
   ├───Folder2
   └───Folder3
```

What i want to achieve is to tab complete -filter parameter with folder name only.

```
script.ps1 -filter Fol
```

'hit tab' will result to:

```
script.ps1 -filter Folder1
```

I tried to specify filter parameter as `System.IO.FileInfo` but tab completion added `./` before folder name

```
Param(
    [System.IO.FileInfo]
    [string]$filter = "*", 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a new argument completer with [`Register-ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter):

```
# script.ps1
param(
  [string]$Filter
)

# do stuff with $Filter
```

```
# the argument completer
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName script.ps1 -ParameterName Filter -ScriptBlock {
  param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameters)

  if($script:FileNames -isnot [string[]]){
    $script:FileNames = (Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot).Name
  }

  # The Where-Object clause will ensure that `Fol` is taken into account when tab completing
  return $script:FileNames |Where-Object {$_ -like "$wordToComplete*"} |ForEach-Object { "'$_'" }
}
```